# Create a Function which will tell us if an array is sorted or not in C programming

Tags: arrays, c, sorting, pointers, structure

**New to C programming ^^**.

I am working on an assignment, and I have to create a function that verifies if my array is sorted. I have to use a predefined template of code and solve it in a certain way.

**Description** :

Let's create a function which will tell us if an array is sorted or not. What is sorted? :-)

Write a function that takes an integer array as a parameter (input) and returns a boolean (true/false).

Your function should return true if the integer array is sorted in either ASC(ascending) or DESC(descending) order.
Your function should return false if the integer array is not sorted.

Numbers will be from -2_000_000 to 2_000_000
Array might have duplicate(s).

**I have to use this to solve my problem**.

```
#ifndef STRUCT_INTEGER_ARRAY
#define STRUCT_INTEGER_ARRAY
typedef struct s_integer_array
{
    int size;
    int* array;
} integer_array;
#endif


bool my_is_sort(integer_array* param_1)
{

}

The inputs that will be used to verify my code:

Exemple 0: 

Input: [1, 1, 2]
Output: 
Return Value: true 

Exemple 1: 
Input: [2, 1, -1]
Output: 
Return Value: true 

Exemple 2: 
Input: [4, 7, 0, 3]
Output: 
Return Value: false 

Exemple 3: 
Input: []
Output: 
Return Value: true
```

Here is my code :

```
#include <stdbool.h>
#ifndef STRUCT_INTEGER_ARRAY
#define STRUCT_INTEGER_ARRAY
typedef struct s_integer_array
{
    int size;
    int* array;
} integer_array;
#endif


bool my_is_sort(integer_array* a)
{
    if (a->size == 1 || a-> size == 0)
    {
        return true;
    }

    int i;
    for (i=0;i<a->size;i++)
    {   //ascending order
        if (a->array[i] <= a->array[i+1]){
            return true;
        }else if (a->array[i] >= a->array[i+1]){
            return true;
        } else {
        return false;
    } 
    }
}
```

**The output I get to verify my code** :
[The output failure i get](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Pzecb.png)

My mistake is in the input -> Input: [4, 7, 0, 3]
My code returns true when it is supposed to return false.
It returns true because of the first two indexes 4 is less then 7 so my code assumes that it is in ascending order, but it's not the case I want my code to keep looping to the next one before it returns a boolean. To check if the number after 7 is greater then 7 or not. but I dont know how to do this in code.

Thank you guys!

I know it might be a dumb question for a lot of you, but please help. I am new to this, and I freaking love programming.

Comment: You are always returning on the first iteration of your loop. If you were not you'd also index past the end of the array on the last iteration of the loop so you should use `size -1` in your for loop condition. Try adding a flag variable outside the loop. When you compare two values they can be ascending, descending, or equal. Compare the current result against the flag and if it is the opposite return false.

Comment: `if (a <= b) { ... } else if (a >= b) { ... } else { puts("This line cannot be printed."); }`. Because if `a` is not `<= b` then it must be `> b`, at least for integers. (Floating point numbers in implementations with a NaN -- which is almost all of them -- can execute the `puts`, if either or both of the compared expressions are NaN.) Plus what  @RetiredNinja said.

Comment: Just as a side note: the correct type for defining array (or other) sizes is `size_t` from `stddef.h`, not `int`...

Comment: Two elements are sorted as well, so you could simply do `if(size <= 2) return true;`.

Comment: Hint: Find first pair `array[n]` and `array[n+1]` that are *not* equal and remember that relation ship (e. g. <=). Then if any subsequent pair does not fit (in this example: >), return false. If you don't find such misfit (i. e. the loop completes), return true.

Comment: Note well: if you cannot debug, you cannot program.  Just adding some printf's would have allowed you to track down most/all of your bugs, never mind using an actual debugger.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This function will check if the array is sorted.

```
#ifndef STRUCT_INTEGER_ARRAY
#define STRUCT_INTEGER_ARRAY
typedef struct s_integer_array
{
    int size;
    int* array;
} integer_array;
#endif

typedef enum
{
    des,
    notdetermined;
    asc;
}SORT_TYPE;


bool my_is_sort(integer_array* a)
{
    bool result = true;
    SORT_TYPE sort = notdetermined; 
    if (a && a -> array && a -> size > 2)
    {
        for(int i = 0; i < a -> size - 1 && result; i++)
        {
            switch(sort)
            {
                case notdetermined:
                    if(a -> array[i] > a -> array[i + 1]) sort = des;
                    else if(a -> array[i] < a -> array[i + 1])) sort = asc;
                    break;
                case asc:
                    if(a -> array[i] > a -> array[i + 1])) result = false;
                    break;
                case des:
                    if(a -> array[i] < a -> array[i + 1])) result = false;
                    break;
            }
        }
    }
    return result;
}
```

https://godbolt.org/z/xnM7MYz6b

Answer (score 1):

This is pretty simple. Check for *both* ascending/descending sort can be done in a single pass.

We do this by having *two* flag variables, one for ascending sort [still] being true and one for descending sort [still] being true.

In the loop, if the current elements being compared are not equal, one of the directions *must* be out-of-sort.

Here is some refactored code. It is annotated:

```
#include <stdbool.h>

#ifndef STRUCT_INTEGER_ARRAY
#define STRUCT_INTEGER_ARRAY

typedef struct s_integer_array {
    int size;
    int *array;
} integer_array;
#endif

bool
my_is_sort(integer_array *a)
{

    if (a->size <= 1)
        return true;

    int i;

    // true if [still] have ascending sort
    int ascend = 1;

    // true if [still] have descending sort
    int descend = 1;

    // the value of the "previous" array element
    int prev = a->array[0];

    // the value of the "current" array element
    int cur;

    for (i = 1;  i < a->size;  ++i, prev = cur) {
        // early escape -- neither direction is in sort
        if (! (ascend || descend))
            break;

        // get current array value
        cur = a->array[i];

        // compare against previous value
        int dif = cur - prev;

        // elements are the same -- no change in status
        if (dif == 0)
            continue;

        // one of the directions has to be out-of-sort
        if (dif < 0)
            ascend = 0;
        else
            descend = 0;
    }

    return (ascend || descend) ? true : false;
}
```

---

**UPDATE:**

Here is a slightly faster version:

```
bool
insort_fix1c(integer_array *a)
{
    const int *arr = a->array;
    int size = a->size;

    if (size <= 1)
        return true;

    int i;

    // true if [still] have ascending sort
    int ascend = 1;

    // true if [still] have descending sort
    int descend = 1;

    // the value of the "previous" array element
    int prev = arr[0];

    // the value of the "current" array element
    int cur;

    for (i = 1;  i < size;  ++i, prev = cur) {
        // get current array value
        cur = arr[i];

        // compare against previous value
        int dif = cur - prev;

        // elements are the same -- no change in status
        if (dif == 0)
            continue;

        // one of the directions has to be out-of-sort
        if (dif < 0)
            ascend = 0;
        else
            descend = 0;

        // early escape -- neither direction is in sort
        if ((ascend | descend) == 0)
            break;
    }

    return (ascend | descend) ? true : false;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

> Write a function **that takes an integer array as a parameter**
> (input) and returns a boolean (true/false).

The parameter of this function

```
bool my_is_sort(integer_array* a)
```

does not accept an integer array.

In this for loop

```
int i;
for (i=0;i<a->size;i++)
{   //ascending order
    if (a->array[i] <= a->array[i+1]){
        return true;
    }else if (a->array[i] >= a->array[i+1]){
        return true;
    } else {
    return false;
}
```

there are checked only the first two elements of an array pointed to by the data member `array` of an object of the type `struct s_integer_array`. All other elements are not checked due to return statements within the for loop.

I can suggest the following straightforward function implementation shown in the demonstrative program below.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdbool.h>

bool is_sorted( const int a[], size_t n )
{
    bool sorted = true;
    
    size_t i = 1;
    
    while ( i < n && a[i-1] == a[i] ) ++i;
    
    if ( i < n )
    {
        if ( a[i-1] < a[i] )
        {
            while ( ( ++i < n ) && !( a[i] < a[i-1] ) ) { /* empty */ }
            sorted = i == n;
        }
        else
        {
            while ( ( ++i < n ) && !( a[i-1] < a[i] ) ) { /* empty */ }
            sorted = i == n;
        }
    }
    
    return sorted;
}

int main(void) 
{
    int a1[] = { 1, 1, 2 };
    size_t n = sizeof( a1 ) / sizeof( *a1 );
    
    for ( size_t i = 0; i < n; i++ )
    {
        printf( "%d ", a1[i] );
    }
    putchar( '\n' );
    
    printf( "The array is sorted is %s\n", is_sorted( a1, n ) ? "true" : "false" );
    putchar( '\n' );

    int a2[] = { 2, 1, -1 };
    n = sizeof( a2 ) / sizeof( *a2 );
    
    for ( size_t i = 0; i < n; i++ )
    {
        printf( "%d ", a2[i] );
    }
    putchar( '\n' );
    
    printf( "The array is sorted is %s\n", is_sorted( a2, n ) ? "true" : "false" );
    putchar( '\n' );

    int a3[] = { 4, 7, 0, 3 };
    n = sizeof( a3 ) / sizeof( *a3 );
    
    for ( size_t i = 0; i < n; i++ )
    {
        printf( "%d ", a3[i] );
    }
    putchar( '\n' );
    
    printf( "The array is sorted is %s\n", is_sorted( a3, n ) ? "true" : "false" );
    putchar( '\n' );

    return 0;
}
```

The program output is

```
1 1 2 
The array is sorted is true

2 1 -1 
The array is sorted is true

4 7 0 3 
The array is sorted is false
```

Comment: I like the two-separate-loops approach for its efficiency, but the loop condition looks pretty unlucky to me. Wouldn't you rather just `return false;` immediately – or, if a single return point is required `{ sorted = false; break; }`?

Comment: @Aconcagua It is a bad idea to use several breaks or returns in a simple function. It is a bad style of programming.

Comment: In my 15 years of professional code writing that additional (hidden) if-check wouldn't have passed any code review, though (relying on compiler to optimise away being unpreferrable). Seems once more not all people apply the same criteria...

Answer (score 0):

This is how I would approach something like this. It's a little different and more complex than what you've been asked for, but I'm hoping you can adapt the concept to your code and finish your assignment.

The problem with the code in the question is that it returns after only comparing the first two values in the given array. Instead it needs to compare enough values to decide if the first comparison where the values are not equal is ascending or descending and then continue until a comparison breaks that rule or the end of the array is reached.

For that I've used a flag variable to keep track of previous comparisons. If any comparison is the opposite of previous results the array is unsorted. If the end is reached without finding an opposite the array is sorted.

I used an `enum` for this, but an int with a value of 0 for undetermined, -1 for descending, and 1 for ascending (or any other 3 values you like) would work fine too.

Hopefully this helps you complete the assignment. Good luck!

```
#include <stdio.h>

typedef enum
{
    sortUnknown = 0,
    sortAscending,
    sortDescending,
    sortUnsorted
} SortType;

const char *sortNames[] =
{
    "   Unknown",
    " Ascending",
    "Descending",
    "  Unsorted",
};

SortType is_sorted(int* arr, int size)
{
    if (size <= 1)
    {
        return sortUnknown;
    }

    SortType overallSortType = sortUnknown;
    for (int i = 0; i < size - 1; ++i)
    {
        if (arr[i] < arr[i + 1])
        {
            if (overallSortType == sortDescending)
            {
                return sortUnsorted;
            }
            overallSortType = sortAscending;
        }
        else if (arr[i] > arr[i + 1])
        {
            if (overallSortType == sortAscending)
            {
                return sortUnsorted;
            }
            overallSortType = sortDescending;
        }
    }
    return overallSortType;
}

void print(int *arr, int size, SortType st)
{
    printf("%s : ", sortNames[st]);
    for (int i = 0; i < size; ++i)
    {
        printf("%d ", arr[i]);
    }
    printf("\n");
}

int main()
{
    int arr1[] = { 1, 1, 2 };
    SortType st = is_sorted(arr1, 3);
    print(arr1, 3, st);

    int arr2[] = { 2, 1, -1 };
    st = is_sorted(arr2, 3);
    print(arr2, 3, st);

    int arr3[] = { 4, 7, 0, 3 };
    st = is_sorted(arr3, 4);
    print(arr3, 4, st);

    int arr4[] = { 3 };
    st = is_sorted(arr4, 1);
    print(arr4, 1, st);

    int arr5[] = { 1, 1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 6, 6, 6, 7, 8, 9 };
    st = is_sorted(arr5, 17);
    print(arr5, 17, st);

    return 0;
}
```

Demo: https://ideone.com/RkfEWI

Output:

```
 Ascending : 1 1 2 
Descending : 2 1 -1 
  Unsorted : 4 7 0 3 
   Unknown : 3 
 Ascending : 1 1 1 1 2 2 2 3 4 5 6 6 6 6 7 8 9
```